# Changing wx.TextCtrl style flags dynamically

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have this code on my project. what i would like to do is:

1. Make the text field read only so no one can type in it.
2. Append the text to the field via button event
3. If wrong button is pressed and the wrong value is appended, press the right button to overwrite the text field.

I don't think this will work because my text field is already in a read only format.
Is there a way to change the style flags dynamically or what can i do?

In other words, how can i overwrite value of a read only field?

```
def trig_dir(e):
        self.text.Clear()
        dialog = wx.DirDialog(None, "Choose a directory:",style=wx.DD_DEFAULT_STYLE | wx.DD_NEW_DIR_BUTTON)

        if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            global boxstat
            boxstat+=dialog.GetPath()

        self.text.AppendText(boxstat)
        dialog.Destroy()
```

if a user changes their mind, this function runs again.

Comment: There is no problem with changing the text of a control with `wx.TE_READONLY` style programmatically, you really should just test it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/wxPython/Widgets/wx.TextCtrl.html), `wx.TE_READONLY` makes the text in TextCtrl not user-editable; this does *not* prohibit the text to be altered from within the program. Consider the example:

```
import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=title, size=(350,200))
        self.text = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, style=wx.TE_READONLY)
        self.btn1 = wx.Button(self, -1, "Right button")
        self.btn2 = wx.Button(self, -1, "Wrong button")
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.text, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer.Add(self.btn1, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer.Add(self.btn2, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Fit()

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.RightButtonPress, self.btn1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.WrongButtonPress, self.btn2)

    def RightButtonPress(self, evt):
        self.text.AppendText("Right!")

    def WrongButtonPress(self, evt):
        self.text.Clear()
        self.text.AppendText("Press again!")

app = wx.App()
top = Frame("Hello World")
top.Center()
top.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: hi @Andrey, your input works fine.

I'm not sure how i would implement this in my application.

My code is here!! I'm using py2.7 32bit with wxpy

click browse, choose a dir.. then click browse again, choose a dir.. and look at the field and u will see it appends.

I am not sure how to implement your example, your example has two buttons and mine has one! (browse)

http://pastebin.com/nxF6Xq3X

Comment: What do you need? Do you need `boxstat` and `self.text` to contain only the directory chosen in the last browse? Then you have to *overwrite* `boxstat` instead of appending stuff to it (`boxstat = dialog.GetPath()` instead of `+=`), and clear `self.text` contents before writing there.